# How to define an interface in typescript for a deep object with variable keyed sub-objects

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a interface type I am calling ThemeType:

```
export interface ThemeType {
  mobileWidth: string;
  font: {
    fontName: string;
  };
  colors: {
    color: {
      darkest: string;
      dark: string;
      middle: string;
      lightest: string;
      light: string;
    };
  };
}
```

For a theme that looks like:

```
export const SiteTheme: ThemeType = {
  mobileWidth: '900px',
  font: {
    esteban: "'Esteban', 'Georgia', serif",
    apercu: "'Apercu', Helvetica, sans-serif",
  },
  colors: {
    rose: {
      darkest: '#D4B1A6',
      dark: '#F0C9BC',
      middle: '#F5DBD2',
      light: '#F9E9E4',
      lightest: '#FAF3F0',
    },
    coffee: {
      darkest: '#6F6150',
      dark: '#A6795B',
      middle: '#CA9673',
      light: '#CFA992',
      lightest: '#E7CEBF',
    },
    cream: {
      darkest: '#E8D3A6',
      dark: '#F7E5C0',
      middle: '#F9EECF',
      light: '#FFF9EA',
      lightest: '#FFFBF2',
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't see how to define an interface with repeated structures under keys, and where those repeated structures each have their own unique key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface ColorSet {
      darkest: string
      dark: string
      middle: string
      light: string
      lightest: string
}

export interface ThemeType {
  mobileWidth: string;
  font: {
    fontName: string;
  };
  colors: {
    [color: string]: ColorSet
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach above has a drawback, the intellisense wont recognize the keys since
it can be any string. I would use Record utility type to overcome this and you can set them as optional or not using Partial.

example:

```
type FontTypes =
  | "'Esteban', 'Georgia', serif"
  | "'Apercu', Helvetica, sans-serif";

type Fonts = "esteban" | "apercu";

interface ColorSet {
  darkest: string
  dark: string
  middle: string
  light: string
  lightest: string
}

type Colors = "rose" | "coffee" | "cream";

export interface ThemeType {
  mobileWidth: string;
  font: Partial<Record<Fonts, FontTypes>>;
  colors: Record<Colors, ColorSet>;
}
```

docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html